# FFmpeg not linked correctly?

Tags: ffmpeg, sdl, linker-errors

I'm trying to load and display a video using SDL, and FFmpeg.
So far I've run into alot more trouble than any other libraries I've tried.
Now I can run the program and see an almost black screen. BUT the problem is, if I uncomment any of the lines in the `loadVideo(...)` function, I will get a linker error.

I'm using the files from "FFmpeg git-4cdea92 64-bit Dev", and the "FFmpeg git-4cdea92 64-bit Shared" to get the DLL-files. Located at the link:
http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

```
void loadVideo(string file) {
    //Initialize video
    //av_register_all();
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
    //if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, file.c_str(), NULL, NULL) != 0) {
        //printf("Unable to open video file '%s'!\n", file.c_str());
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just found the answer to my own question. I don't know why I recieved the errors I did, but changing to 32-bit library worked. So I guess whenever a library specifies 32/64-bit, it means the visual studio version, and NOT the Windows version?

Anyways, I if people happen to stumble across this...
32-bit dll-files goes into the 64-bit Windows folder. (Aka. SysWOW64) if you have a 64-bit Windows.